# check all elements against values in an array JQuery

Tags: jquery, each

```
$('.list_body').each(function(){
     var job_no = $(this).data('job_id');
     if($.inArray(job_no, return_data)) {
         $.noop();
     }
     else {
         $(this).closest('div.list_body').remove();
     }
});
```

`.list_body` data-attribute holds a job id reference.

What I need to do is remove the particular `.list_body` div if the job id is not included in the array `return_data`.

Not sure if the `.each()` function is the best practice here as currently it seems to get rid of a div even though the job id is in the array.

Comment: You need to show the HTML as well

Comment: and `$.inArray` returns `-1` if it's not in the array, so if the `job_id` is the first in the array, the element is getting removed anyway. And if it's not in the array, `-1` is still going to be truthy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, `$.inArray` returns `-1` when not found, so there's an immediate logic flaw. Secondly, `this` refers to the element you want to remove, so looking for the `closest` with the same selector is redundant. Try this:

```
$('.list_body').each(function(){
    var $el = $(this);
    if ($.inArray($el.data('job_id'), return_data) == -1) {
        $el.remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var return_data = [2]

$('.list_body').each(function(){
    var job_no = $(this).data('job_id');
    if($.inArray(job_no, return_data) > -1) {
        $(this).closest('div.list_body').remove();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2bgpS/)

A better solution will be

```
$('.list_body').filter(function(idx, el){
    return $.inArray($(this).data('job_id'), return_data) > -1;
}).remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2bgpS/2/)